# Pagespeed ignoring app.yaml directives

Tags: php, google-app-engine, pagespeed

Pagespeed service is turned on for our PHP application and is working as evidenced by the many pagespeed modifications that are being made to our outputted HTML.

Pagespeed is only implementing it's default rewriters. My app.yaml directives requesting additional rewriters seem to be ignored. Comments are not stripped, whitespace is not collapsed, what am I doing wrong? Here is my app.yaml.

```
application: redacted
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

pagespeed:
 enabled_rewriters:
 - RemoveComments
 - CollapseWhitespace
 - LeftTrimUrls
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://appengine.google.com/
Open your application, Click on "Application Settings", Scroll down to "PageSpeed Service" and click on "Flush Cache".